# Reverse Engineering, no relationships after import my script to mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, stub, relationships

For some reason i'm not able to open my model anymore, it's corrupted, so i'm trying to import from MySQL to create a new model for manipulating but always get this error when import it:

```
WARNING: Table `macrotelecom_django`.`perfil` not found. Stub was created.
WARNING: Table `macrotelecom_django`.`Agentes` : Foreign key `fk_Agentes_Perfil1` :     Referred column `macrotelecom_django`.`perfil`.`idPerfil` not found. Stub was created.
WARNING: Table `macrotelecom_django`.`usuariologin` not found. Stub was created.
WARNING: Table `macrotelecom_django`.`Agentes` : Foreign key `fk_Agentes_UsuarioLogin1` :   Referred column `macrotelecom_django`.`usuariologin`.`idUsuarioLogin` not found. Stub was created.
WARNING: Table `macrotelecom_django`.`clientes` not found. Stub was created.
WARNING: Table `macrotelecom_django`.`Albaran` : Foreign key `fk_Clientes_has_Productos_Clientes1` : Referred column `macrotelecom_django`.`clientes`.`idCliente` not found. Stub was created. 
WARNING: Table `macrotelecom_django`.`productos` not found. Stub was created.
WARNING: Table `macrotelecom_django`.`Albaran` : Foreign key `fk_Clientes_has_Productos_Productos1` : Referred column 
...
```

For some reason, it's not able to import foreign keys properly, always says 'table not found' when the creates always realize before constraints, what could it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be a case-sensitive issue as reported in MySQL bug report [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=47981).

> Potentially Workbench could check for `lower_case_table_names`
>   variable value before starting reverse-engineering and adopt
>   `SqlIdentifiersCS` as needed, but that migh lead to undesirable mix of
>   casing in the model. For example several schemata were
>   reverse-engineered from different DBMS that use different value for
>   `lower_case_table_names`. So user has to explicitly set
>   `SqlIdentifiersCS` parameter in Workbench and apply same rule set
>   every time.

Comment: Thanks! I use xampp with mac os x but i'm not able to fix lower_caste_table_names, so i change my table names (thanks to God were few...) to lower case, i know that for future, thanks again and forgive for delay of my response!